# Is there any implementation of File Pipes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pipe, named-pipes

do you know if there is any type of pipe in C# that's implemented used a disk file.
We have to transfer a file to another process as we write so we thouhght it would be nice if there was a implemented pipe using a file.
In this comunication there will be a "producer" that is saving a file while the other "consumer" is replicating it to other servers. We don't want to block the process that saves the file (producer) while the consumer is replicating the file across the network.
On using pipes we've seen there are named and anyonymous pipes on C# but they seem to work only on memory.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Why can't you just use a NetworkStream between the two processes?

Comment: @DavidAnderson We don't want  to block the thread that's saving a file to disk while the other is processing the data from the other process. The second process (consumer) will be slower than the first process (producer) so it will block the producer. I think I forgot that on the question, I'll edit it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard about file-based pipe, however you can use [File-mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx#base.using_a_file_mapping_for_ipc), but it doesn't seem to fit with what you want to do. A simple IPC (named pipe) between your processes (file-write-finished message sending), in parallel with the file write, might be much simpler.